# How do I add to a customer attribute a value?

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute

I have a custom customer attribute and I want to assign a value to that attribute for a specific customer. 
This is how I get my customer:

```
$customer_email = "test@test.com";
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId(1);
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
```

The custom customer attribute id is : `cat_id`.

How do I add a value to the attribute for a specific customer using its email address? THx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the setter method then save your customer:

```
$customer_email = "test@test.com";
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId(1);
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
$customer->setCatId($yourId);
$customer->save();
```